# Adding 3rd party JS libraries to Ionic within the proper workflow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova, bower

I have been using jQuery Mobile for a hybrid app for the past few months and wanted to get exposure to Ionic and Angular.js so i am atempting to rebuild it.  My JQM app relies on xml2json.js and I am completely unfamiliar with Cordova, Bower, Gulp, Node.js and several of the other tools used to build and deploy Ionic apps.

Is there a right way, or a right place to add xml2json.js so when I build it gets pulled in automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was to use Bower, however it required a bit of setup.

Install Bower (I'm on a mac, you may not need sudo)
`sudo npm install -g bower`

If you are behind a firewall (like at work) before installing you my need to run
`npm config set strict-ssl false` to fix UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

After installing Bower again if you are behind a firewall you will need to do the following
`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` forces bower to download modules using the HTTP address

You will also need to edit .bowerrc in your project folder to get rid of the bower specific UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

```
{
    "strict-ssl": false
}
```

After that you can run the install command
`bower install xml2json --save`

If you installed Ionic with npm then .bowerrc has an override to the save directory which will save to `/www/lib/[plugin folder]/`

Disabling ssl on node and bower is bad for security and there are better instructions on how to accomplish these tasks the right way, however this is how I got it to work inside my corporate office environment in a short amount of time.